# What is the difference in between 'Apache Environment', 'Environment' and 'PHP Variables'?

Tags: apache, configuration, environment-variables, php

I'm using **PHP 7.2.11** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**.

I've installed **PHP 7.2.11** and **Apache/2.4.35 (Win32)** using the latest version of **XAMPP for Windows**.

I executed below code and saw the output into my web browser. My queries are based only on this output.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I saw almost similar configuration variables with same values under the headings **'Apache Environment'** and **'PHP Variables'**.

The same bare entity name appearing under the heading **'Apache Environment'** got encapsulated into `$_SERVER` superglobal array under the heading **'PHP Variables'**.

E.g. `MIBDIRS` under the heading **'Apache Environment'** becomes `$_SERVER['MIBDIRS']` under the heading **'PHP Variables'** with same value. 
This is the case for all configuration variables appearing under **both** the headings.

I saw three additional configuration variables under the heading **'PHP Variables'** which are missing from the configuration variables appearing under 'Apache Environment'.

Following are those variables alongwith their values :

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']            /dashboard/phpinfo.php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']  1540099695.445
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']        1540099695
```

Why so?

What are the configuration variables appearing under the heading **'Environment'**? Are the different from the configuration variables appearing under the headings **'Apache Environment'** and **'PHP Variables'**? What's the role of these configuration variables?

Among all the configuration variables coming under all the three headings which configuration variables does appear inside the `$_ENV` superglobal array?

Among all the configuration variables coming under all the three headings provide values if used with `getenv()` function?

Please answer my question in point-wise and step-by-step manner in an easy to understand language.

Comment: I also have the same question. Did you figure it out?

Also do you know whether there is a way to export a variable from "Apache Environment" to "Environment"?